# Ninject - Request scope has already been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-extensions

I'm using `Ninject` and the extensions EventBroker and DependencyCreation in an MVC 3 application. I've installed and am using the Ninject.MVC3 package and therefore the `OnePerRequestModule`.

I'm attempting to inject a service, called `IParentService` into a controller. `IParentService` has a dependency on `ChildService` created via the DependencyCreation extension (no hard reference).

Both services are registered on a local event broker instance (local to `ParentService`).

I want the `IParentService` to be scoped per request and I want the dependency and event broker to be disposed of at the same time as the `IParentService`, however, I'm getting a `ScopeDisposedException`. **What am I doing wrong?**

Some code:

**Service Definitions:**

```
public interface IParentService
{
}

public class ParentService : IParentService
{
    [EventPublication("topic://ParentService/MyEvent")]
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}

public class ChildService
{
    [EventSubscription("topic://ParentService/MyEvent", typeof(bbv.Common.EventBroker.Handlers.Publisher))]
    public void OnMyEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {            
    }
}
```

**Kernel registration (NinjectWebCommon)**

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IParentService>().To<ParentService>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .OwnsEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker")
            .RegisterOnEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker");

        kernel.DefineDependency<IParentService, ChildService>();
        kernel.Bind<ChildService>().ToSelf()
            .WhenInjectedInto<ParentService>()
            .InDependencyCreatorScope()
            .RegisterOnEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker");            
    }
```

**Stack trace:**

```
[ScopeDisposedException: The requested scope has already been disposed.]
   Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope.NamedScopeExtensionMethods.GetScope(IContext context, String scopeParameterName) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.namedscope\src\Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope\NamedScopeExtensionMethods.cs:118
   Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope.NamedScopeExtensionMethods.GetScope(IContext context, String scopeParameterName) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.namedscope\src\Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope\NamedScopeExtensionMethods.cs:126
   Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<InNamedScope>b__0(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.namedscope\src\Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope\NamedScopeExtensionMethods.cs:40
   Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingConfiguration.GetScope(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Bindings\BindingConfiguration.cs:119
   Ninject.Planning.Bindings.Binding.GetScope(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Bindings\Binding.cs:224
   Ninject.Activation.Context.GetScope() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:123
   Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.TryGet(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:110
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:150
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +191
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, String name, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:50
   Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation.ContextPreservationExtensionMethods.ContextPreservingGet(IContext context, String name, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.contextpreservation\src\Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation\ContextPreservationExtensionMethods.cs:56
   Ninject.Extensions.bbvEventBroker.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<RegisterOnEventBroker>b__0(IContext ctx, T instance) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker\src\Ninject.Extensions.bbvEventBroker\EventBrokerExtensionMethods.cs:45
   Ninject.Planning.Bindings.<>c__DisplayClass29`1.<OnDeactivation>b__28(IContext context, Object instance) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Bindings\BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs:513
   Ninject.Activation.Strategies.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Deactivate>b__3(Action`2 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Strategies\BindingActionStrategy.cs:42
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:32
   Ninject.Activation.Strategies.BindingActionStrategy.Deactivate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Strategies\BindingActionStrategy.cs:42
   Ninject.Activation.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Deactivate>b__4(IActivationStrategy s) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:72
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:32
   Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.Deactivate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:72
   Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(CacheEntry entry) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:253
   Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Forget(IEnumerable`1 cacheEntries) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:242
   Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Clear(Object scope) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Caching\Cache.cs:197
   Ninject.Web.Common.<>c__DisplayClass2.<DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest>b__1(IKernel kernel) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\OnePerRequestHttpModule.cs:74
   Ninject.GlobalKernelRegistration.MapKernels(Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\GlobalKernelRegistration.cs:75
   Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\OnePerRequestHttpModule.cs:74
   Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.<Init>b__0(Object o, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\OnePerRequestHttpModule.cs:56
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

**EDIT - MORE DETAILS**

The error is thrown within a deactivation delegate that is set in the call to `RegisterOnEventBroker`, where the code attempts to unregister any objects registered on the event broker. It fails because the event broker scope has been disposed, presumably because the parent service has been disposed. As far as I am aware, Ninject will only call OnDeactivation delegates for objects with lifetimes other than Transient scope, so why this doesn't work when the parent service is registered in `RequestScope` confuses me. Transient scope is not sufficient for the parent service because I'm experiencing memory leaks because of this issue.

I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug in the EventBroker extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first bind `IParentService` to `ParentService` then use self-binding of concrete type `kernel.Bind<ParentService>().ToSelf()` to define Object scope and event broker.

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IParentService>().To<ParentService>();


        kernel.Bind<ParentService>().ToSelf()
       .InRequestScope()
       .OwnsEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker")
       .RegisterOnEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker");

        kernel.DefineDependency<IParentService, ChildService>();
        kernel.Bind<ChildService>().ToSelf()
            .WhenInjectedInto<ParentService>()
            .InDependencyCreatorScope()
            .RegisterOnEventBroker("ParentServiceBroker"); 
    }
```

**Edited:**
if the type you’re resolving is a concrete type (like ParentService above), Ninject will automatically create a default association via a mechanism called implicit self binding.
Like this:

```
 kernel.Bind<ParentService>().ToSelf();
```

On the other hand implicit self-bindings are generated in the default Object Scope which is `Transient`. This is why your code does not run in `Request` scope.

For more information see [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject)

**Edited 2:**

There is a bug in `bbvEventBroker` extension in `Request` scope which cause EventBroker was disposed before disposing of the object which registers on that EventBroker. Therefore in `OnDeactivation` method of the object there is no EventBroker which its Unregister can be invoked and `ScopeDisposedException` wan thrown.

```
    public static IBindingOnSyntax<T> OwnsEventBroker<T>(this IBindingOnSyntax<T> syntax, string eventBrokerName)
    {
        string namedScopeName = "EventBrokerScope" + eventBrokerName;
        syntax.DefinesNamedScope(namedScopeName);
        syntax.Kernel.Bind<IEventBroker>().To<EventBroker>().InNamedScope(namedScopeName).Named(eventBrokerName);
        syntax.Kernel.Bind<IEventBroker>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.ContextPreservingGet<IEventBroker>(eventBrokerName)).WhenTargetNamed(eventBrokerName);
        return syntax;
    }
```

You can see in `OwnsEventBroker` method NamedScope define in scope of the object (`ParentService`) which enforce it to dispose before the object (`ParentService`).

On the other hand in `OnDeactivation` of the object (`ParentService`) there is need to EventBroker which disposed earlier.

```
    public static IBindingOnSyntax<T> RegisterOnEventBroker<T>(
        this IBindingOnSyntax<T> syntax, string eventBrokerName)
    {
        return
            syntax.OnActivation((ctx, instance) => ctx.ContextPreservingGet<IEventBroker>(eventBrokerName).Register(instance))
                  .OnDeactivation((ctx, instance) => ctx.ContextPreservingGet<IEventBroker>(eventBrokerName).Unregister(instance));
    }
```

[EventBrokerExtensionMethods.cs](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.bbvEventBroker/EventBrokerExtensionMethods.cs)

The solution is creating the object tree with `NamedScope`. Define parent in `Request` scope while it define a `NamedScope` for its children (Publisher/Subscriber) and owns the event broker (`OwnsEventBroker`). Then define a Publisher(`ChildService1`) and a Subscriber (`ChildService2`) in the named scope was defined by the parent. In this way you can ensure that the event broker's owner will be disposed after their childen.

Comment: Thanks Kambiz, that does resolve the error. Can you elaborate a little more on what was wrong with the way I was doing it and why it needs to be done this way?

Comment: I've doubled checked this but in my test I'm injecting IParentService not the concrete type. This appeared to fix my problem but actually it was just using your first binding instead of the second 'self' binding. If I use your code and inject a 'ParentService' instance I get the same exception.

Comment: @nukefusion You are right; I think this is bug. I found that  When Scope is set to `Request`, EventBorker `NamedScope ` is disposed  while `ParentService` is in disposing stage.  When `OnDeactivation` try to call `ctx.ContextPreservingGet<IEventBroker>(eventBrokerName)` to get EventBroker instance, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Ninject core currently deactivates objects that are in the scope of an object before deactivating the object itself.

Changing the order seems to fix that problem. Although before pushing that change I have to check what side effects this can have for other situations.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Remo. Is there an open issue for this so I can track it?